# setting innodb_tmpdir on MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, innodb

version:10.0.33-MariaDB

trying to perform an ALTER TABLE and it's running out of diskspace during the rebuild, currently using /tmp from @@tmpdir. I'm trying to set @@innodb_tmpdir from NULL to another directory and it continuously fails with the below error:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> set @@innodb_tmpdir = '/tmp/inno_tmpdir';
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'innodb_tmpdir' can't be set to the value of '/tmp/inno_tmpdir'
MariaDB [(none)]> show warnings\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1210
Message: InnoDB: Server doesn't have permission in the given location.
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Level: Error
   Code: 1231
Message: Variable 'innodb_tmpdir' can't be set to the value of '/tmp/inno_tmpdir'
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've given the directory full permissions to mysql.

```
 [root@host tmp]# ls -lrt | grep inno_tmpdir
drwxrwxrwx.  2 mysql          mysql             4096 Oct 16 12:15 inno_tmpdir
```

the odd part is that I can set @@innodb_tmpdir /tmp (which @@tmpdir is set to ) /usr/tmp or /var/tmp

```
MariaDB [(none)]> set @@innodb_tmpdir = '/var/tmp';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]> set @@innodb_tmpdir = '/usr/tmp';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]> set @@innodb_tmpdir = '/tmp';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Some Linux security systems like selinux or apparmor keep a list of directories that a given service is allowed to use, and if they try to access some unauthorized location, Linux returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

`innodb_tmpdir` is looked at startup, unlike some other (like `innodb_data_home_dir`, `innodb_undo_directory`)

To search for tablespaces into other directories, you must add them (comma separated in Linux, I believe) to `innodb_directories`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with MySQL 5.6.49.
What I did - it's just added full permission to the new temp directory:

```
chmod 777 /tmp/inno_tmpdir
```

and then I was able to set innodb_tmpdir = '/tmp/inno_tmpdir'